# how to get 7 dates continuously with date and year

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

i have a module in that i have 7 buttons all the 7 buttons indicates date for action, i.e first button has current date, second button has tomorrow date, third button has day after tomorrow date likes go on till 7th button, i implemented code from one post to get info like that, but my problem is i can't convert date into string, i need to remove and replace the output value and send it to server

here my sample code :

```
 func addDaystoGivenDate(baseDate:NSDate,NumberOfDaysToAdd:Int)->NSDate
{
    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    let CurrentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let CalendarOption = NSCalendarOptions()

    dateComponents.day = NumberOfDaysToAdd

    let newDate = CurrentCalendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents, toDate: baseDate, options: CalendarOption)
    return newDate!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    let newDate = addDaystoGivenDate(NSDate(), NumberOfDaysToAdd: 1)
    print(newDate)
}


my output is : 2016-04-06 08:35:59 +0000

but my expected output is : 06/04
```

can anyone solve my issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to format your date right with this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM"

let dateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate!)
// dateStr now contains the string "06/04"
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM"

let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate)
```